# MongoDB schema configuration

Tags: mongodb, schema, database-schema

I am very new to MongoDB. So, I don't know very  much about schema. I found Data Models Schema at MongoDB Documentation and it also said  Collections do not enforce document structure. But I also want to make schema configuration at the database level, not from Program. Is it possible? If it is possible, suggest me the way how to do it or share me a link for tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has no schema, you can write whatever you want wherever you need. Obviously you want to keep information in some way it's consistent to each other. To make it simple, making a comparison between RDBMS and NoSQL, tables are what collections are in MongoDB, and records are documents, you always want to keep documents of the same nature in a collection, but they can have different structure. I personally think, that it's a more human way to see things.

There's a good example where you want to keep products of a supermarket, where every product could have some information in common (like price, name, EAN13) but there's thousand of attributes that are different to them (Weight, Height, Grams or liters, Inches of a TV, power on a microwave, and so on), and that would take 3 tables to accomplish on RDBMS and just one collection on NoSQL.

There's a lot of differences between NoSQL and RDBMS, and these options suit better at some cases than others. Not only data is important, scalability, availability, the approach to ACID is important to analyze too.

Thinking NoSQL is very different from RDBMS, normalization takes a different approach (N to N requires a VERY different way to see the problem).

That being said, and going on your question, there's a way or approach to schemas, sometimes I use [MongooseJS](http://mongoosejs.com/index.html) for NodeJS which is an ODM for MongoDB where you can specify some fields for a document, even relations, data types, etc.

Regards!